# pymssql utf8: queries with back slash

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, unicode, pymssql

I'm a bit curious what is the pythonic/best way to solve my issue.

A short code example:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect("SERVER", 'sa', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE', charset='utf8')

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT 'foo\bar' as bs_field"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0]
# missing \, returns u'foobar'

sql = "select FIELD_CONTAINING_BACKSLASH from TABLE"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0]
# all OK here

sql = "SELECT 'foo\\bar' as bs_field"
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0]
# this is OK too
```

I want to know why the \ is missing in the first example - is there a better solution as quoting every single sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot!

Has nothing to do with mssql, it's just python strings.

```
r'bla\bla'
'bla\\bla'
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Indeed. Note that in *some* databases (eg for the default settings of MySQL and older versions of PostgreSQL), backslashes are indeed special and you would need to write `r"SELECT 'foo\\bar'"` or `"SELECT 'foo\\\\bar'"`. This is not ANSI SQL standards-conformant behaviour and SQL Server doesn't do it, but the confusion is another good reason to use parameterised queries in preference to SQL string literals.

Comment: True, I'm using these most of the time, but if you forget about python basics it doesn't help :-)